# extract only columns that contains 'True' value from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   False   False   True    True    False
1   False   True    True    False   False
```

I want to filter it and get a dataframe with columns that has at least one `True` value.

```
    col2    col3    col4
0   False   True    True
1   True    True    False
```

Comment: `df.loc[:,df.any()]` should do

Comment: [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) is very well explained here. It has a similar example of the question(example 2).

Comment: @anky ... excellent solution.

Comment: @Anshul thanks, initially i thought this might be a duplicate which is why I commented instead of answering but cant find any :-)

Comment: Not trying to sound too dramatic, but solutions like these for a python programmer are like 'secret winning spices' in the kitchen for a chef. Once known, you would end up using them everywhere.

Comment: @Anshul I get your point , apologies but once you are comfortable with the docs, you tend to think what i did

Comment: @anky - cool. Like in this case, you mean the help documentation for pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are looking for `any` on which you can call `loc`

```
df.loc[:,df.any()]
```

---

```
   col2  col3   col4
0  False  True   True
1   True  True  False
```

Comment: Only way I could out golf this was to get absurd... `df.T[df.any()].T
`